# Can you use 'checkout scm' to get the git commit without actually checking out the repository?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm using a scripted pipeline in Jenkins and trying to retrieve the commit that triggered the build. I'm currently using 'checkout scm' in my Jenkinsfile but I'm looking for a way to get the commit without actually checking out the repository as it can be quite large!

Is there a way to do this? Thanks

Comment: The phrase "get the commit" could mean "check out the commit", or it could mean "get the raw hash ID" or "get the log message" or something along those lines. What, precisely, do you mean? Note that Jenkins has an easy way to use a shallow clone, which may be what you want. Just remember that shallow clones add limitations to Git.

Comment: I mean I'm looking to get the commit sha ID of the jenkinsfile in use i.e. at the point in time of the build. I ideally don't want to have to checkout the repository though. I can get the commit sha ID using 'checkout scm' but I'm looking to get the commit sha ID without actually checking out the repository. As I said I don't know if this is even possible

Answer (score 1):

To limit only to last commit I use GitSCM `CloneOption` [extension](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/). That avoid clone everything, useful in scenarios with big repos.

```
checkout([
    $class: 'GitSCM', 
    branches: [[name: myBranch]], 
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
    extensions: [[
        $class: 'CloneOption', 
        noTags: true, 
        reference: '', 
        shallow: true, 
        depth: 1
        timeout: 5
    ]], 
    submoduleCfg: [], 
    userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: myCid, url: myRepoUrl]]
])
```

- shallow (boolean): Perform shallow clone, so that git will not download the history of the project, saving time and disk space when you just want to access the latest version of a repository.
- depth (optional boolean): Set shallow clone depth, so that git will only download recent history of the project, saving time and disk space when you just want to access the latest commits of a repository.